# render an event in fullcalendar with custom data on the fly when changing the input element

Tags: jquery, html, fullcalendar

I am trying to render a custom event on the fly to show on the fullcalendar on the page,
i am getting the already existing events from the url 
$(.id).fullCalendar('addEventSource', 'the file name where the json is rendered');

but i dont have any clue on how to get the new event rendered

Comment: @saravna kumar, look at http://arshaw.com/js/fullcalendar-1.6.4/demos/json.html they give example

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a quick example using the default.html from demos folder. I am assuming you create an event save it to the db and want the event(s) to render on the calendar. Refer to this part of the documentation:

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/renderEvent/
http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/rerenderEvents/

This example uses renderEvent. On click of the button, an event is created and rendered on the calendar.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href='../fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<link href='../fullcalendar/fullcalendar.print.css' rel='stylesheet' media='print' />
<script src='../lib/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='../lib/jquery-ui.custom.min.js'></script>
<script src='../fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        var date = new Date();
        var d = date.getDate();
        var m = date.getMonth();
        var y = date.getFullYear();

        $('#button_id').click(function() {
            var newEvent = {
                title: 'NEW EVENT',
                start: new Date(y, m, d)
            };
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'renderEvent', newEvent , 'stick');
        });

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            editable: true
        });

    });

</script>
<style>

    body {
        margin-top: 40px;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-family: "Lucida Grande",Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
        }

    #calendar {
        width: 900px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        }

</style>
</head>
<body>
<button type="button" id="button_id" onClick=>Create new event</button>
<div id='calendar'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Updated for 2020: $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'renderEvent', newEvent , true);

Answer (score 1):

The accepted Answer is correct. If it does not work for someone, you may check the position of your code. the `$('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'renderEvent', newEvent, 'stick');` has to be after your initial .fullCalendar() call. I struggled half an hour to figure this out :)